# get file in featureActivated encounter an error : “Value does not fall within the expected range”

Tags: c#, sharepoint, feature-activation, spfile

I set to copy a text file from a module to SharePoint server directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="MyModule">
    <File IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Path="MyModule\newFile.txt" Url="MyModule/newFile.txt" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

After that, in featureActivated, I am going to get the file by this code:

```
                try
                {
                    SPFile newFile = myWeb.GetFile(properties.Definition.RootDirectory + "\\MyModule\\newFile.txt");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
```

I got this exception : “Value does not fall within the expected range”.
What is wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

The [SPWeb.GetFile Method (String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms476063(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) get file from SharePoint site, the properties.Definition.RootDirectory return the local path, you will get the exception.

I suggest you upload the file into document library like "Site Assets" in root web, then get file in feature receiver.

Example code:

**Elements.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MyModule" Url="SiteAssets" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
    <File IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="MyModule\newFile.txt" Url="newFile.txt" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

**Feature Receiver**

```
try
{
    SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
    SPFile newFile = myWeb.GetFile(myWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/newFile.txt");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about SiteAssets.
There is no warranty that this document library exists in every site that I am going to activate my feature.
What is your idea?

Comment: We can only upload the file into "SiteAssets" in root web, and get file from the root web. Check my updated reply.

Comment: You mean, we can be sure of existing "SiteAssets" document library in root web every site collection we are working on?

Comment: You can use PowerShell to check if this library in root web every site collection,